# Wide background css using :before tag

Tags: css

Can someone help me regarding this http://www.alerto24.com/
Why is there a wide space to the right and the horizontal scrollbar is visible?

Answer (score 0):

Both your footer and content section have a right margin of -100% which causes the scrollbar. Disable that CSS property for both elements and the scrollbar is gone.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort and answering my question. I will try your solution. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

please change below css

```
#content::before {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../images/site-bg-b.jpg") no-repeat scroll 50% 0;
  content: " ";
  /*left: -100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;*/
}

#footer::before {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #032d34;
  content: " ";
  /*left: -100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;*/
```

}

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort and answering my question. I will try your solution. Thankyou!

Comment: did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a structure problem in your `#footer` and `#content`.
For example. You put background properties to apply a 100% background in `:before` and a `max-width: 920px` combined with `width: 100%` in footer element, which appears like a contradiction.

I suggest you these modifications :

You remove `#content:before` and `#footer:before` properties. You can create a container div in your `#content` element which contains the width of the website like this :

```
#content .container { 
  width: 920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And you apply background properties on `#content` which has `width: 100%;`

```
#content {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue; /* you put your background properties on it */
}
```

Also, you do the same for footer :

```
#footer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    /* max-width: 920px; remove this line */
    background: blue; /* you put your background properties on it */
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px 0 15px;
    color: #fff;
}

#footer .wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto; /* you use this property to center this container as it is on the website */
    padding: 0 0 50px;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 920px; /* you apply width on this container instead of the #footer container */
    letter-spacing: -5px;
}
```

**EDIT** : I've made a JSFiddle to explain my thoughts 
[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/5t7oynbf/1/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort and answering my question. I will try your solution. Thankyou!